# Google BigQuery Error: Syntax error: Illegal input character "%"

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm trying to use Google's BigQuery NodeJs library, however, I keep getting this error.

Input example:

```
{"name": "John Doe", "gameid": "048.611"}
```

And here is an example of my query.

```
const query = 'select * from gametag_ae.users where GAMEID like %' + gameid + '% where NAME like %' + name + '% LIMIT 1';
```

And this is the error that I'm getting:

```
(node:6802) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Syntax error: Illegal input character "%" at [1:64]
```

I can't use the operator `%` in this case, but it's necessary for this query.

What would be a better approach to get it working?

Comment: Wildcard patterns have to be in quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below

```
const query = 'select * from gametag_ae.users where GAMEID like "%' + gameid + '%" AND NAME like "%' + name + '%" LIMIT 1';
```